# Find the domain of the function $f+g$, where $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x}$ and $g(x)=x^2$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, domain-theory

I know that Dom$ (f) = (-\infty,4]$ Dom $(g) = \mathbb{R}$, but the problem is Dom$(f+g)$.

Please also tell Dom$(f-g)$

Comment: What have you tried? Also please use the latex symbols...

Hint : any polynomial function can be defined over $\mathbb{R}$ naturally and square root of a function is well-defined in $\mathbb{R}$ only for nonnegative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g(x)=x^2$ does exists for every $x in \mathbb R$ and since $\sqrt{4-x}$ require that $4-x \geq 0$, the Domain of $f+g$ is simply

$$
D = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R}:x \geqslant 4} \right\}
$$

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me if the domain will remain same for f-g or not.

Comment: Yes, because the "problem" arises from the square root and as long as you add or subtract functions defined for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$ nothing change.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome!